# How to Pass parameters as a querystring to httpClient.post in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am passing the parameters as querystring to HttpClient.post with the Header
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' .

I checked the many questions earlier asked in Stack overflow but not get the success..

In service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders,HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

searchPerson(contactNo) {
  let header = new HttpHeaders(); 
    header = header.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  let params = new HttpParams();
   params =params.set ('grant_type','password');
   params =params.set ('username',contactNo);

   return this.http.post('Some Url',params,{headers:header });
 }
```

In login.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 //import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {FactoryService} from '../../services/factory.service';

  constructor(private factory: FactoryService) { }

logMeIn(contactNo:string){
 this.loading = true;
   this.factory.searchPerson(this.contactNo).subscribe(
    data=> { console.log(data.token);},
    err=> {    
              this.loading = false;
              console.log(err.message); 
          },
    ()=>{
          this.loading = false;
          console.log('Login process done');
          }
  );
}
```

throwing exception: Http failure response for URL: 400 Bad Request

Comment: you are using which language in the backend?

Comment: ASP.NET web api-2

Comment: you just have to permit all value in your back end controller

Comment: ok, but.. is there anything wrong in this code ?

Comment: you didn't parse your response to json